# How to iterate through a SortedMap with same ordering?

Tags: java, dictionary, sortedmap

One can iterate through a SortedMap by using the iterator from `myMap.entrySet().iterator()`. But does this iterator preserve the ordering of the sorted map object ?

The SortedMap interface has no own methods to iterate through the entries. What is the standard way to iterate **ordered** through the entries ?

Comment: The first part of your text is the answer to your question.

Comment: What about enhanced for loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard iterator is guaranteed to keep the iteration order exactly the same as the natural order of the keys, for both keys and entries. This is stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) and can be easily tested.

On the other hand, if you're interested in preserving iteration order over keys and entries in the same order that the keys were inserted, then you're looking for a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: I do not say at all that you are wrong, but how can you test that? I mean, inserting and iterating once and finding that the order is the same does not guarantee that the next time it will happen the same way, isn't it?

Comment: You probably mean (keys) "natural order" instead of "insertion order", right?  If you want to iterate over insertion order, what you need is a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: @fge you're, of course, correct. I expanded my answer citing both kinds of maps

Comment: @SJuan76 but you can repeat the same experiment many times and find out that the results are as expected. Besides, the iteration order is guaranteed in the documentation.